# how do you make an ssh connection within php

Tags: php

I need to use ssh on php. I eanble these two dlls in php.ini file:

```
extension=php_ssh2.dll
extension=php_ssh2.dll
```

I am still getting this error, any ideas what I might be missing?'

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()
```

Comment: look at the output of `phpinfo();` and see if the extension was loaded properly.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: It may seem silly, but did you save your `php.ini` file? And are you sure it's the correct one? I had a similar issue once where settings I changed in the `php.ini` weren't recorded b/c I had multiple versions on my server. That was a forehead slapper for sure.

Comment: in phpinof(), I dont see any ssh. I saved and restarted iis.

Comment: if there's no ssh mentioned in phpinfo, then you didn't modify the right .ini file, and/or the .dll can't be found/loaded.

Comment: @Marc B, I put the dll files in ext directory and in php.ini, I put these lines extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_ssh2.dll

Comment: Why are you trying to load the same `dll`s twice?

Comment: I've been looking at this quite some time now, I tryied everything not working. I'd appreciate if someone can share ssh2_dll.

Comment: On most systems there are multiple php.ini files - a pitfall I learned the hard way. Look at the phpinfo() output, since it states exactly where the used ini file is located.

Comment: I coudn't ge the ssh working. I will attempt using cCurl.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the libssh2 DLL's too.

I think [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), would work better for you actually. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```